# Time complexity for Babylonian Method

Tags: performance, algorithm, big-o, time-complexity

What would be the time complexity for Babylonian Method? is it log(n) where n is the number we want to find the squared root for? If so, why is this so?

Comment: I feel like this source might be what you want, which talks about [Newton's Method](http://en.citizendium.org/wiki/Newton's_method#Computational_complexity), which is what algorithms like the Babylonian Method are based on.

Comment: @kurtzbot Historically, saying that the Babylonian method is based on Newton's method is quite funny.

Comment: Haha, sorry, did not mean to cause confusion.  I remember learning this and had to do some googling to refresh my memory.  Please correct me if I am mistaken.

Comment: Unless you mean it is funny because of the names, and not mathematically.  In which case I agree :P

Comment: @kurtzbot I think he means it's funny because, presumably, the Babylonian method predates Newton's method by... thousands?... of years.

Comment: @kurtzbot I meant it's funny because the Babylonians have developed the method some 2000 years before Newton was born. Of course, post Newton, it's a special case of Newton's method.

Comment: Ahh, I re-read the source, and it says that `For example, the well known and very efficient Babylonian method for calculating square roots is equivalent to using Newton's method to solve the equation x^2 - y = 0  for x`.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Looking at [the wikipedia section for the Babylonian method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Methods_of_computing_square_roots#Babylonian_method) we can see that the relative error at step k, e<sub>k</sub>, satisfies the equation e<sub>k</sub> < 2<sup>-f(k)</sup>, where f(k) is defined recursively as follows:

f(1) = 2 and f(k+1) = 2 * f(k) + 1 for n > 1

By induction,  f(k) = 3 * 2<sup>k-1</sup> - 1

Let n be the input to our algorithm, which stops when we are sure that the total error is less than a constant m

The error at step k, E<sub>k</sub>, satisfies the equation E<sub>k</sub> = e<sub>k</sub> * n

Therefore the algorithm will terminate once e<sub>k</sub> * n < m

This will occur when 2<sup>f(k)</sup> > n/m which is equivalent to f(k) > log<sub>2</sub>(n/m)

That equation is true when 2<sup>k-1</sup> > (log<sub>2</sub>(n/m) - 1)/3 which is true when k > log<sub>2</sub>((log<sub>2</sub>(n/m) - 1)/3)+ 1

Therefore the algorithm will terminate in O(log(log(n/m)+1)) steps.

Using [this logarithmic summation formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_logarithmic_identities#Summation.2Fsubtraction) you can show that log(log(x)+c)) = O(log(log(x)).

Therefore the Babylonian method takes O(log(log(n/m)) steps

Answer (score 0):

I guess steps would be O(log2(log to the base E0 (m/n)) 
where E0 is the error at zeroth iteration i.e when we choose seed value 
m is error allowed in the ans and n is the input to the algorithm.
You can refer to this for complete explanation for recursive function of error :http://www.math.harvard.edu/library/sternberg/slides/lec1.pdf