# Finding out Big O for this loop

Tags: algorithm, math, big-o

So I was just messing around the jsfiddler and played with the following algorithm to calculate the `sqrt` without using the `Math.sqrt`:

```
var counter = 0;

function sqrt(x){
    var a, b;

    a = 1;
    b = x;
    while (Math.abs(a - b) > 0.1){
        a = (a + b) / 2;
        b = x / a;
        counter++;
    }

    return a;
}

var x = 64;
var result = sqrt(x);

alert('Result = ' + result + ' (number of iterations ' + counter + ')');
```

jsfiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/2wx99yxj/

Could you please help me to determine what would be the Big O complexity of the above algorithm? I tried and ended up somewhere around O(1/2*LogN) but I'm not sure and would actually need some help. Thanks

### Solved

As stated above - a duplicate of [Babylonian Method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12309432/time-complexity-for-babylonian-method). I slightly updated the code to reflect the `error threshold` as follows:

```
function sqrt(x){
    var a, b, error;

    error = 0.1;
    a = 1;
    b = x;
    while (Math.abs(a - b) > error){
        a = (a + b) / 2;
        b = x / a;
        counter++;
    }

    return a;
}
```

and the BigO result is: **O(log(log(x/error))**

Comment: @sasha just tried it. works fine so far :)

Comment: @sasha that's right - it's float. at the beginning it will be (1 + 64) / 2 = 32.5

Comment: @interjay interesting did not know that

Comment: Nice. Thank you guys. Appreciated.